# How to Revert SUPEE-8788 v1 and bash SUPEE-8788 v2

Tags: magento-1, security, patches, supee-8788, supee-8788v2

I installed SUPEE-8788 v1, but now I need to revert it and install SUPEE-8788 v2.

**How can I revert SUPEE-8788 v1 and then install v2?**

I installed it using SSH bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-R` or `--revert` to revert a patch.

For example:

```
./PATCH_V1.sh -R
./PATCH_V2.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! But in that case I also need the v1 file on my server, right? Because I installed v1 a month ago and removed the file. So how can I install v1 again? I can not download v1 from the Magento site.

Comment: @HenkZ yes you also need the v1 patch file. Brent Peterson keeps an updated repo with all the patches if you need: https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches

Comment: I tried your code, but I get the following error: `-bash: ./PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh: Permission denied` Is that because we installed it a time ago?

Comment: @HenkZ so it's a permission issue try to chmod 777 the patch file

Comment: Thanks, solved that. But when I want to revert it, I get the following error: `checking file downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 373.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED` How can I solve that?

Comment: @HenkZ https://community.magento.com/t5/Security-Patches/PATCH-8788-Hunk-1-FAILED-at-373/td-p/50621

Comment: Thanks! I read a lot of problems that are related to V2 of the file. Is there a way to check if I already run V2? Because after reading a lot, I doupt that I have V1.

Comment: @HenkZ in `app/etc/applied.patches.list` there's the list of patches that have been applied

Comment: Sadly it is V1. Do you know a solution to solve the error. Because I also replaced the file Curl.php for the default 1.9.2.4 file. But that does also not work.

Comment: @HenkZ no sorry I'm out of ideas here

Answer (score 0):

```
"sh SUPEE-8788.sh" Command for Installing Patch AND
"sh SUPEE-8788.sh -R" Command for Reverting Patch.
```